# libcurl multi asynchronous support

Tags: libcurl

From the examples and documentation, it seems libcurl multi interface provides asynchronous support in batch mode i.e. easy handles are added to multi and then finally the requests are fired simultaneously with curl_multi_socket_action. Is it possible to trigger a request, when easy handle is added but the control returns to application after request is written on the socket?

**EDIT:**
  It'll help in firing request in the below model, instead of firing requests in batch(assuming request creation on client side and processing on the server takes same duration) 

 
Client -----|-----|-----|-----| 
 
Server <   >|-----|-----|-----|----|

Answer (score 1):

The multi interface returns "control" to the application as soon as it would otherwise block. It will therefor also return control after it has sent off the request.

But I guess you're asking how you can figure out exactly when the request has been sent? I think that's only really possibly by using [CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION.html) and seeing when the request is sent. Not really a convenient way...

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I wanted to know when the request was sent. Instead of  firing requests in batch, I was thinking of below model(assuming request creation on client side and processing on the server takes same duration)   <br/>

Client    -----|-----|-----|-----| <br/>
Server         |-----|-----|-----|----|

Comment: sorry. I'm not sure how to format the post. I wanted to explore other models apart from firing requests in batch mode. One option is to fire request once the previous one was written to the socket. But I think there is not much different theoretically between these approaches.

Comment: Daniel, I looked at the source. It looks like state is maintained in each easy handle. It seems CURLM_STATE_DO_DONE indicates completion of request transfer. Instead of CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION, for our internal use I'm planning a patch to enable state look up on easy handle. Do you see any issue with this approach?

Comment: That can be done yes, I worked on adding that info once but it was never completed/merged. I could see us get back to working on that and you can help out! See this patch for a starting point: http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2013-08/0028.html

Comment: Thanks Daniel. That's pretty useful. I'll look into this.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the documents this:
https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/hiperfifo.html

It's combined with libevent and libcurl.
When running, the program creates the named pipe "hiper.fifo"

Whenever there is input into the fifo, the program reads the input as a list
of URL's and creates some new easy handles to fetch each URL via the
curl_multi "hiper" API.

The fifo buffer is handled almost instantly, so you can even add more URL's while the previous requests are still being downloaded.

Then libcurl will download all easy handles **asynchronously** by calling `curl_multi_socket_action` ,so the control will return to system.

Comment: Use case is slightly different from these examples. You can find more details about this in the PR - https://github.com/curl/curl/pull/1314